# If you remove an amenitiy, are your animals affected?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

In animal crossing, you can add amenities in the back row of your camping (can't remember the exact name).

Those tents rise the max friend level from 7 to 10 for the animals of that type. But you can only have 2 tents, and there are 4 types.

So if I rise an animal of the nature type to 10, but then remove the nature tent, do that nature animal fall back to level 7? or does it stay level 10?

Also, if the tent is not there, but in my inventory, can I still level up my animals?

PS: Sorry for the vagueness, would like to go get the exact name for them, but the app is down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe just having purchased the amenity is enough to unlock the higher levels - I have been levelling up all four, and all of the caps have been being raised (and staying raised).